# SQL Alter an value from 1 to 0

Tags: php, sql, statements

Hey im looking for a SQL statement that let me alters the int in the database to a zero for inactive - i have no idea how to write the SQL query like that,and how the php code would look.

This is my best guess..

```
select id,active 
from posts 
where id = '42' and (active = '1')
```

This is the current statement, well '42' is a var in the php i can find the current row 
and it prints out this

```
id active 
42 1
```

in the sql database - how can i alter the int to a zero?

Comment: Assuming you are using MySQL: [MySQL Update Query](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm)

Comment: You need to learn `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry i'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `UPDATE` command to update the rows already in the database. That UPDATE command execute against some key for eaxmple in your example that is `ID`.

The UPDATE Command syntax will be like this:-

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnWhichNeedsTObeUpdated = newValueforColumn
WHERE KeyColumn = KeyColumnIdentifierValue
```

For eaxmple for your case:-

```
UPDATE posts SET active = 0
WHERE id = 42
```

[Have a look for MYSQL UPDATE syntax manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: I was just going to update the question that i solved it, sorry!

Thanks anyway!